# "kafka.bootstrap_servers" is not a configurable parameter for Amazon OpenSearch Ingestion pipelines

Tags: apache-kafka, opensearch

I am trying to integrate confluent cloud kafka topic with AWS OpenSearch via ingestion pipeline.

As per the official documentation of AWS OpenSearch, we can now use Kafka Plugin to integrate Kafka with Opensearch.

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/data-prepper/pipelines/configuration/sources/kafka/

But I am getting an error when I am trying to configure an ingestion pipeline where the source is confluent kafka and destination(sink) is opensearch.

I am using the following config:

```
`version: '2'
kafka-pipeline:
  source:
    kafka:
      bootstrap_servers:
        - '127.x.x.x:xxxx'
      topics:
        - name: Topic1
          group_id: groupID1
  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts:
          - >-
https://xxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
        aws:
          sts_role_arn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/xxxxx'
          region: us-east-1
        index_type: xxxxx`
```

But I am getting the following error upon config validation:
[image: Validation error]